# error: cannot find symbol import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit, hamcrest

I am using Java 1.7 and Gradle 4.10.3. I tried using various gradle dependencies like 
testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.1' and 
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'. Can someone please let me know what is the correct dependency for hamcrest CoreMatchers. If not, can you please suggest me an alternative for containsString.

Comment: is your spring or spring boot application ? can you show `build.gradle` ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this dependency:

```
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
```

Comment: thanks @Matthias. can you please let me know if this dependency is compatible with java 1.7.

Comment: Hamcrest is build with JDK 1.5. Java 1.7 is ok.

Comment: Hamcrest 2.2 is also ok for JDK 7

Comment: thanks @Matthias. I added this testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.1' dependency in build.gradle . But I am still seeing the same compilation error : cannot find symbol.

Comment: I checked it and it works. `testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.1'`

Comment: What is the full path of your Java Class? Is it located unter src/test/java?

Comment: Hi @Matthias. thanks for  the help. I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was a default import of hamcrest-core 1.3 version from junit 4.12 and mockito 1.9.5.
Made the following changes in build.gradle

```
testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.1'
    testCompile (group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    testCompile ('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
```